# Nestuite: Suitescript variable for logged in or not?

Tags: netsuite

I have a web store (Suitebuilder) and I've got a specific vendor that only wants us to show prices when a customer is logged in. All other vendors allow prices to be shown regardless. Is there a suitescript variable that lets me know whether someone is logged in that I can use to customize a template based on a specific vendor and whether someone is logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but below are some approaches

```
var isLoggedIn = "<%=getCurrentAttribute('customer','entityid')%>" != "";
```

You can check for the logged in customer email in your script to confirm whether is there any actual login or not.

Also you can try `nlapiGetLogin` if you're using any suitelets for custom login functionality

> **nlapiGetLogin()**
> Returns the NetSuite login credentials of currently logged-in user.
>
> This API is supported in user event, portlet, Suitelet, RESTlet, and SSP scripts. For information about the unit cost associated with this API, see API Governance.
>
> Returns nlobjLogin

```
var login = nlapiGetLogin();  //Get credentials of currently logged-in user
```

If you are using more like a SSP application then probably you can try this out

```
<%    
var shoppingSession = nlapiGetWebContainer().getShoppingSession(); 
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try detecting a cookie, then alter the page layout using JS or CSS to show different prices. I don't know them off hand, but there are Cookie values that let you know when a customer is logged in.

There may also be some URL parameters you could detect, but I can't remember them.